# Sending defer message delivery and change default account using Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I use Outlook 2010 and Powershell 2.0.

I want send a Outlook message, and delay delivery programmatically of a message using Powershell.

How can I create a new Outlook email and immediately defer delivery?

Comment: Any idea how you would add CC recipients? Is there an API that you referenced?

Comment: Maybe properties in $Mail object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try this:

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application  
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)  
$mail | Get-Member
```

you'll get a list of all methods/properties available on the mail object.

One property is DeferredDeliveryTime. You can set it like this:

```
#Stay in the outbox until this date and time
$mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = "11/2/2013 10:50:00 AM"
```

Or:

```
#Wait 10 minutes before sending mail
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.AddMinutes(10)
$mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = $date
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$ns = $ol.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

# call the save method yo dave the email in the drafts folder
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$null = $Mail.Recipients.Add("xxxx@serverdomain.es")  
$Mail.Subject = "PS1 Script TestMail"  
$Mail.Body = "  Test Mail  "

$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.AddMinutes(2)
$Mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = $date #"2/11/2013 10:50:00 AM"

$Mail.save()

# get it back from drafts and update the body
$drafts = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderDrafts)
$draft = $drafts.Items | where {$_.subject -eq 'PS1 Script TestMail'}
$draft.body += "`n foo bar"
$draft.save()

$inspector = $draft.GetInspector  
$inspector.Display()


# send the message
$draft.Send()
```

References:

[Create Outlook email draft using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453723/create-outlook-email-draft-using-powershell)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-HP010355051.aspx

**Update**

To change default account:

```
$Mail.SendUsingAccount = $ol.Session.Accounts | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $FromMail}
```

References:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2011/08/08/outlook-sending-emails.aspx
[Outlook automation - Change Sender Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201848/outlook-automation-change-sender-account)